# Python list to BigQuery repeated string

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm working with Google BigQuery using Python application.

I have a dataframe with a field which contains lists, let's call it "keywords". I also have a BigQuery table whose keywords field is STRING and mode=REPEATED.

This is the schema of my BigQuery table:

[My BigQuery table schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqBqx.png)

```
SCHEMA = [
    bq.SchemaField("id", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
    bq.SchemaField("fecha", "DATE", mode="NULLABLE"),
    bq.SchemaField("keywords", "STRING", mode="REPEATED")
]
```

And this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
from google.cloud import bigquery as bq

df_dict = {
    "id": ["asdf173","qwer783","vcda619"],
    "fecha": [date(2019,1,15), date(2019,1,28), date(2019,2,12)],
    "keywords": [['a','b'], ['c','d','e'],['f']]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)

client = bq.Client()
dataset = client.dataset(dataset_name)
table_ref = dataset.table(table_name)

client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table_ref).result()
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to upload the dataframe into the BigQuery table:

> 400 Provided Schema does not match Table project-id:dataset-name.table-name. Field keywords has changed type from STRING to RECORD.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Hi Felipe and welcome, Can you provide a screenshot of your table structure from the webUI for advanced troubleshooting

Comment: Thank you Tamir, do you mean the schema? I still have my table empty.

Comment: Yes the schema so we'll be able to compare between your code and table structure give the error you are getting

Comment: Done! Here you have it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqBqx.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this error message:

> 400 Provided Schema does not match Table project-id:dataset-name.table-name. Field keywords has changed type from STRING to RECORD.

And the structure of the table you provided

[image]

You can see that you are trying to insert an ARRAY aka RECORD into a string field.

You need to change the type of the field keywords from String to RECORD to solve your problem

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tamir. I am not allowed to change the BigQuery table's structure. It doesn't depend on me, the client has this structure and it must be as it is.

Comment: So change your data into json and stringy it before the insert. Use JSON sql functions to fetch the data or if possible parse this on your python code

Comment: @FelipPellicer, Hope my answer helped you if so will be great if you can accept it, See how in this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235 and this one as well: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers